# Change the Description of a value of a node

Tags: python, scripting, interface, node-editor, add-on

Is it possible to change the Description of a value of a node in Blender python. I am coding an addon, and want to set description for a value of a node.
But by default, it shows:

> "Input value used for unconnected socket"

Thanks in advance!